# The HTTP method received is not valid. Only POST is accepted

Tags: php, xml

OK, I have this php file for my HSBC bank processing using the API, I have this working fine on 2 of my other websites, however the SAME file is failing on the other two sites, I have no idea why. My web developer is stumped and decided to create a test file, Here is the code from the test file:

```
<?php
echo "payment processing...";
$amount = 100;// round($_POST["realamount"], 2) * 100;
$fullName = "test";//$_POST['name'];
$Address1 = "test";//$_POST['address1'];
$Address2 = "test";//$_POST['address2'];
$city ="test";// $_POST['city'];
$county = $city;
$postcode = "test";//$_POST['zipcode'];
$country = "GRB";//$_POST['country'];

$phone = "test";//$_POST['telephone'];
$email = "a@a.com";//$_POST['emailaddress'];    

$cardNumber = "337877666233434";//$_POST['cardNumber'];
$cardExp = "03/2011";//$_POST['ccmonth'] . "/" . substr($_POST["ccyear"],2,2);
$cvdIndicator = "111";//$_POST['cvdIndicator'];
$cvdValue = "111";//$_POST['cvdValue'];
$issueNumber = "111";//$_POST['issueNumber'];
$cardType = "VI";//$_POST['cardType'];


$testRead = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EngineDocList>
<DocVersion>1.0</DocVersion>
<EngineDoc>
    <ContentType>OrderFormDoc</ContentType>
    <User>
        <Name>xxx</Name>
        <Password>xxx</Password>
        <ClientId>xxx</ClientId>        
    </User>
    <Instructions>
        <Pipeline>PaymentNoFraud</Pipeline>
    </Instructions>
    <OrderFormDoc>
        <Mode>P</Mode>
        <Comments/>
        <Consumer>
            <Email/>
            <PaymentMech>
                <CreditCard>
                    <Number>".$cardNumber."</Number>
                    <Expires DataType='ExpirationDate' Locale='840'>".$cardExp."</Expires>
                    <Cvv2Val>".$cvdValue."</Cvv2Val>
                    <Cvv2Indicator>".$cvdIndicator."</Cvv2Indicator>
                    <IssueNum>".$issueNumber."</IssueNum>
                </CreditCard>
            </PaymentMech>
        </Consumer>
        <Transaction>
            <Type>Auth</Type>
            <CurrentTotals>
                <Totals>
                    <Total DataType='Money' Currency='826'>".$amount."</Total>
                </Totals>
            </CurrentTotals>
        </Transaction>
    </OrderFormDoc>
</EngineDoc>
    </EngineDocList>";
?>
<?php


//$url = "https://www.uat.apixml.netq.hsbc.com";
$url = "https://www.secure-epayments.apixml.hsbc.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$testRead);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result_tmp = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
///////////////////////////////////////
// use XML Parser result
   $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
   xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING,0);
   xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE,1);
   xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $result_tmp, $vals, $index);
   xml_parser_free($xml_parser);    

//print_r($vals);  // print all the arrays.
//print_r($vals[29]); // print only the selected array.
$val1 = $vals[21];
// ProcReturnMsg
$paymentResult = $val1[value];


$result_tmp = "";
$k=0;
$findthis = false;
$findthis2 = false;
foreach ($vals as $val) {
$result_tmp.= $k."{"; 
foreach($val as $d => $a) {
      $result_tmp.="[".$d."]".$a;
      if($d=="tag" && $a=="TransactionStatus"){
          $findthis = true;
      }
      if($d=="value" && $findthis){
          $tResult = $a;
          $findthis = false;
      }

      if($d=="tag" && $a=="Text"){
          $findthis2 = true;
      }
      if($d=="value" && $findthis2){
          $tResult2 = $a;
          $findthis2 = false;
      }

}  
$result_tmp.= "}"; 
$k++; 

} 


echo $tResult2.$tResult;

?>
```

Here is an example of one of the sites not working [gs.net](https://www.glowsticks.net/hsbc_payment_way_test.php)
The output is:
payment processing... The HTTP method received is not valid. Only POST is accepted.

Whereas when I upload this exact same file to some of my other web hosts such as:
[HGL working example](https://www.happyglowlucky.co.uk/hsbc_payment_way_test.php)
The output here is payment processing... Unable to determine card type. ('length' is '15')E
This sounds like an error message, but basically that error is not important, so the latter is what we are trying to achieve in the first link.

I have even uploaded this file to some really basic hosting accounts of mine, sometimes  it will work sometimes it won't, so I'm guessing it's something to do with what the hosting company are allowing or have switched On/Off.

Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: is that actual, produciton code? Ie, you're pasting POST vars straight into the XML as plain text? Injection flaws ripe for the hacking.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, but this is a test file, the info at the top such as card number etc I take you mean, this is not included on the real file.

Comment: Are you able to take the evaluated contents of the `$testRead` variable and send it as a POST request to `$url` using some other method, such as command-line curl, and receive a successful response? Maybe you're running into a quoting issue with PHP which causes weird responses from the API.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that, if it's not too much trouble can you elaborate?  Seems strange how this only effects certain hosts don't you think? It's been driving me mad, currently my only alternative is to buy hosting elsewhere.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if others have the same problem as me, by pasting the above code into a file and seeing which message you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by a PHP upgrade applied to the server and it was driving me crazy.

The solution is to set the following SSL options when specifying the CURL connection.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'RC4-MD5');
```

Comment: You absolute beauty. I had asked my various hosting companies if they had upgraded their php and they told me NO. Having moved my websites to another host I fixed the solution, but of course this was temporary!

Then I tried your fix and like magic it works. This has cost me a fortune in lost orders. How did you find the fix? I googled every page about this it seemed.

Comment: I think I love you for this answer!

Comment: I would also love to know how you found this fix?

Answer (score 0):

check if curl is enabled on those servers that don't work for starters.  use phiinfo() function to check.

Comment: I've done this, infact if you wouldn't mind checking too, here is the file: http://www.glowsticks.net/php.php

Comment: I ran a curl error script and that shows no errors either, so I think the curl side of things is ok.

Comment: does the api documentation not give any more elaborate of an explanation for that error its returning?  Since their api is generating that error I would try contacting their support department and checking their documentation for more info on it.  Somewhat wondering if you need to maybe register a domain with them or something for the script to work right.

Comment: I've done that, HSBC are useless. I know there are other people with the same problem from what I can see in google with no solution as yet.

Re the domains, this doesn't matter I've tried it on many of my hosts with no problems, I am 100% sure you could copy this code yourself from above and upload it to your server as a test php file and it should give the output of "payment processing... Unable to determine card type. ('length' is '15').." which would confirm that your host would work. This is what I'm getting at, I just need to understand why some hosts work and some don't. Can you try it?

Comment: and their documentation is a joke.