# Server/Apache upgrade from 1.3 to 2.0 gives me an error when forcing HTTPS and WWW

Tags: php, apache

My hosting company emailed me yesterday to tell me that they are upgrading Apache... so this morning I found my site down and not working.

The problem was that the browser was giving me "This webpage has a redirect loop" error. The hosting company don't want to help however after some investigating I've located the code which is breaking the site.

I need to force SSL (https) and the www subdomain of the site... the following code used to do this but now it is giving me headaches... can anyone help me amend this as everything I have tried hasn't worked? The following code is put in an include so each page of the site forces (or redirects the user to use https and www in the domain).

```
//force the subdoman and https://...
if($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] != 'www.mysite.co.uk'){
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    $forceurl = isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ? $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : '';
    header('Location: https://www.mysite.co.uk' . $forceurl);
    die();
}


if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 1){
    $newurl2 = "https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    header("location: $newurl2");
    die();
}
```

Comment: On a secret page (since this is a live site), `var_dump()` the values of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and make sure they as as expected. Test this file for all conditions (off domain versus on domain and with SSL versus without SSL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve all of this...

I completely removed the code above and replaced it within the .htaccess like so...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myurl\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I then noticed a problem with the payment API I use wasn't working with the site, I kept getting the following message when trying to make a purchase/payment, "The HTTP method received is not valid. Only POST is accepted". This was odd as I was using POST! The following helped me solve that issue..

[The HTTP method received is not valid. Only POST is accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550890/the-http-method-received-is-not-valid-only-post-is-accepted)

PLEASE NOTE THAT MY HOSTING PROVIDER DID NOT COVER THIS IN THEIR UPGRADE GUIDE/DOCUMENTATION! I will be communicating this to my good friends at 1and1!